# "General permanent error" during libspotify search

Tags: spotify

I've recently started programming in C on my Raspberry Pi. I have downloaded libspotify (I  have the correct version), and have managed it pretty well.

Just recently (~2 hours ago (around 18:00 30/12/2013)), libspotify started to return `SP_ERROR_OTHER_PERMANENT` when checking for a search error in the `search_complete_cb` callback. 
Before the error started occuring, I have built and started the program quite a few times (and thus, logging in many times, during only a short period of time), and to test my 'Search' feature, I have used the same query every time. Then, without making any changes to my program, suddenly there were no results returned after calling `sp_search_create`.

I am worried that the developer account has been somehow suspended for either repeatedly logging in, or because it seemed weird to the spotify crew that I would search for the same query all the time. I don't really know what the problem is caused by. There are no emails or warnings sent to the address connected to the account. The problem has lasted for a while now, so it seems like it's not going away at first.

**Additional details**

- `log_message` tells me there is a `ChannelError(4, 0, search)`. I have also seen `ChannelError(5, 0, search)`, but only once.
- I can still play music from the official Spotify desktop client for Windows.
- I have an earlier version of the program, before I rewrote it to get a bit more structure, that works. The same API key and same credentials are used in both programs, so that excludes a ban. The rewrite does log in, but no results are returned from searching. In the old version, I get a lot of results. All working. I have rebooted the Raspberry Pi several times, but that doesn't seem to help.

If you need any code or other information, I'll be happy to share. Just point out what's needed, because the code is split over a lot of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your old one is working then the problem will be in your rewrite. Don't pay too much notice to the error messages, they're pretty much par for the course, and can be triggered by something as benign as a cache miss. Unless you're actually getting an error callback somewhere, the log messages are meaningless.

As for your problem, I can't really make any guesses without seeing your code. One thing to check and is the most common course of a permanent error is to make sure you're actually logged in. The login process is asynchronous, and any functionality that requires you to be logged in (searching is one of them) will fail before login is completed.

Comment: I had messed up the code for setting my global 'logged in' variable while I was trying to reorganize my threading.. Thank you!